# Users created X month + all users before rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

what i am trying to do is, getting all the users which have been created X month ago + all which have been created before that also.
Just for one month users am using this query

```
EvercamUser.created_months_ago(i).count
```

but i want this query to be for i months ago + all users which already created before.
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class EvercamUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :created_months_ago, ->(i) { where("created_at < ?", i.months.ago.end_of_month) }
end
```

Comment: it will give me the same results as  ???

`EvercamUser.where(created_at: EvercamUser.select(:created_at).order(:created_at).first.created_at..i.months.ago.end_of_month).count`

Comment: it should be. `where(created_at: EvercamUser.select(:created_at).order(:created_at).first.created_at..i.months.ag‌​o.end_of_month)` should equal to `where("created_at < ?", i.months.ago.end_of_month)`